# NameError: name 'user_record' is not defined

Tags: python

I am running this code in Python 3.7.

```
record = ('Dave', 'dave@example.com', '773-555-1212', '847-555-1212')
name, email, *phone_numbers = user_record
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\UsersPythonWizard\Desktop\Python\Python.py", line 2, in <module>
    name, email, *phone_numbers = user_record
NameError: name 'user_record' is not defined
>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined the tuple as `record`, not `user_record`, so `user_record` is not defined. Change one variable to the other and you'll be good.